# Shell Script in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I am runnning shell script in a jenkins pipeline step.
Script is doing maven build and some other stuff.
I want pipeline to fail if maven build fails. 
I am not sure how to do that.

This is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Acceptance Test"
cd .. && cd $PWD/transactions-ui
npm run acceptance-start && cd .. &&  cd $PWD/transactions-test/ && mvn verify -Dserenity.reports=email -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome  -Dwebdriver.provided.mydriver=starter.util.RemoteChromeDriver ; cd .. ;  cd $PWD/transactions-ui/ ; npm run acceptance-stop
echo "Test completed"
```

Following is my jenkins file

```
dir("${workspace}/transactions-test")
                {
                    sh "${workspace}/transactions-test/run.sh"
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define failure. If the exit code of your run.sh script is different than 0, then the build will fail.

Comment: How to save the result of maven build and return it in the end ? As I want to stop the server before the script returns in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set -e` in your bash to exit if any command returns a non-zero status

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
echo "Acceptance Test"
...
```

Bash [set](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) command for reference.

If `set -e` can't work for you, you can examine key cmd result as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Acceptance Test"
cd ..
cd $PWD/transactions-ui
npm run acceptance-start

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "npm run acceptance-start failed"
  exit 1
fi

cd .. 
cd $PWD/transactions-test/
mvn verify \
  -Dserenity.reports=email \
  -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome \
  -Dwebdriver.provided.mydriver=starter.util.RemoteChromeDriver

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "mvn verify failed"
  exit 1
fi

cd .. 
cd $PWD/transactions-ui/
npm run acceptance-stop

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "npm run acceptance-stop failed"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Test completed"
```

Comment: Will it still run the last command (npm run acceptance-stop)  before exit